# Merge two rows into one based on two identifiers

Tags: r, join, merge, row

I have a dataset that contains the information on the bought and sold prices of different products. However, rather than storing the bought and sold for price in the same row, it is stored in two separate rows, which are identified by a bought and sold variable, as shown below.

```
Product|Product Type|Price|Bought|Sold
---------------------------------------
Apples |   Green    |  1  |   0  |  1
---------------------------------------
Apples |   Green    |  2  |   1  |  0
---------------------------------------
Apples |   Red      |  3  |   0  |  1
---------------------------------------
Apples |   Red      |  4  |   1  |  0
---------------------------------------
```

I want to join the bought and sold price into one row, so it looks a little something like this:

```
Product|Product Type|Bought Price|Sold Price
---------------------------------------------
Apples |   Green    |      1     |    2
---------------------------------------------
Apples |   Red      |      4     |    3
```

Here is the code to create my example dataset. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Product <- c("Apples", "Apples", "Apples", "Apples", "Apples", "Apples",
             "Oranges", "Oranges", "Oranges", "Oranges", "Oranges", "Oranges",
             "Buscuits", "Buscuits", "Buscuits", "Buscuits", "Buscuits", "Buscuits")
ProductType <- c("Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Pink", "Pink",
                 "Big", "Big", "Medium", "Medium", "Small", "Small",
                 "Chocolate", "Chocolate", "Oat", "Oat", "Digestive", "Digestive")


Price <- c(2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2,
           5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3,
           6, 4, 1, 8, 6, 2)

Bought <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)

Sold <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
          1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
          1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)

sales <- data.frame(Product, ProductType, Price, Bought, Sold)
```

Comment: is the 1 in bought / sold a coolean yes/no or an indication of quantity?

Comment: Try `sales %>% group_by(Product, ProductType) %>% summarise(BoughtPrice = Price[Bought==1], SoldPrice = Price[Sold ==1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

sales %>% 
  group_by(Product, ProductType) %>% 
  summarise(BoughtPrice = Price[ Bought == 1 ],
            SoldPrice = Price[ Sold == 1 ]) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Product, ProductType, Price, Bought, Sold)
df %>% group_by(Product, ProductType) %>% 
  summarise(Bought_Price = sum(Price * Bought), 
            Sold_Price = sum(Sold * Price))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Product [?]
# Product ProductType Bought_Price Sold_Price
# <fctr>      <fctr>        <dbl>      <dbl>
#   1   Apples       Green            1          2
# 2   Apples        Pink            2          1
# 3   Apples         Red            4          3
# 4 Buscuits   Chocolate            4          6
# 5 Buscuits   Digestive            2          6
# 6 Buscuits         Oat            8          1
# 7  Oranges         Big            3          5
# 8  Oranges      Medium            1          2
# 9  Oranges       Small            3          2
```

Comment: Slightly different solution to the one others have proposed, which is nice :). Thank you very much for the response

Comment: I didn't actually realize there were two other solutions when I posted mine. I guess they are pretty much the same :)

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, we group by 'Product', 'ProductType', and `summarise` to create the 'BoughtPrice' and 'SoldPrice' by subsetting 'Price' where 'Bought' or 'Sold' is 1

```
library(dplyr)
sales %>% 
     group_by(Product, ProductType) %>% 
     summarise(BoughtPrice = Price[Bought==1], SoldPrice = Price[Sold ==1])
```

---

A similar approach with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sales)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) Price[x==1]),
                   .(Product, ProductType), .SDcols = Bought:Sold]
```